# Repeat Ringtone using RingtoneManager in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Currently i am playing ringtones using the following code :

```
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse(selectedRingtone));
ringtone.play();
```

If i play default or system ringtones, they play in loop or repeatedly. But if i choose any other sound from my gallery or media store , it only plays it once. I have gone through some links but i dnt want to use **`MediaPlayer`**. I just need to use **`RingtoneManger`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like file, that you are playing (default), has an information about looping in file itself. If you want to loop other files, you have to make sure, that these files contain information about looping too. It will help you archive your goal with Ringtone.class.

Otherwise, I would recommend you using MediaPlayer. It will allow you to loop sounds even without information about loop in files (why you don't want to use this class?)

Comment: can you guide me how can i put info about looping in any media file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `MediaPlayer`.

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, notification);
player.setLooping(false);
player.start();
```

There is not any method related to loop in [Ringtone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html) and [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html)

Comment: There is for Ringtone since API 28  
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html#setLooping(boolean)

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting Api 28 or greater, there's now a `setLooping` method in `Ringtone`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html#setLooping(boolean)

So in your original example, you just add

```
ringtone.setLooping(true);
```